# java потеря необработанного исключения

Tags: java, исключения

Почему в данном примере было потеряно необработанное исключение:

```
class MyClass {
  int i;

  String getString(){
    try {
      i = i / 0;
      return "try";
    }finally {
      return "finally";
    }
  }
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    String s = myClass.getString();

    System.out.println(s);

  }
}
```

В блоке try происходит деление на 0, что должно породить: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`, однако такого не происходит и метод возвращается строку `finally`.

Comment: `finally` блок выполняется всегда независимо от того, было исключение или нет.

Comment: Если не хотите использовать `catch`, но очень хотите получить исключительную ситуацию, тогда добавьте `finally {
      throw new ArithmeticException(" / by zero");
    }` и будет вам `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`.

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему, то нажмите на галку рядом с ним и на стрелочку вверх

Answer (score 3):

Как уже заметили в других ответах и комментариях, блок `finally` выполняется всегда. Можно удовлетвориться объяснением, что `finally` это тоже обработчик и это он проглатывает исключение. Но если вы вместо `return "finally"` напишите `System.out.println("finally")` то исключение всё-таки будет проброшено вызывающему методу. Чтобы разобраться почему так, нужно посмотреть, как обрабатываются исключения на уровне байткода.

Скомпилируем такой код

```
public class Example {
    private static String test() {
        int i;
        try {
            i = 1 / 0;
        } catch (IllegalStateException exc) {  // Произвольные исключения для примера
            i = 2;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exc) {
            i = 3;
        } finally {
            i = 42;
        }
        return String.valueOf(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }
}
```

И посмотрим, что из него получилось:

```
  private static java.lang.String test();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=3, args_size=0
         0: iconst_1         --
         1: iconst_0           |_ Блок try
         2: idiv               |
         3: istore_0         --
         4: bipush        42 --
         6: istore_0           |- Блок finally
         7: goto          34 --
        10: astore_1         --
        11: iconst_2           |- Блок catch для IllegalStateException
        12: istore_0         --
        13: bipush        42 --
        15: istore_0           |- Ещё один finally?
        16: goto          34 --
        19: astore_1         --
        20: iconst_3           |- Блок catch для IllegalArgumentException
        21: istore_0         --
        22: bipush        42 --
        24: istore_0           |- Опять finally?!
        25: goto          34 --
        28: astore_2         --
        29: bipush        42   |
        31: istore_0           |- И ещё один, но длинный!
        32: aload_2            |
        33: athrow           --
        34: iload_0
        35: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
        38: areturn
      Exception table:
         from    to  target type
             0     4    10   Class java/lang/IllegalStateException
             0     4    19   Class java/lang/IllegalArgumentException
             0     4    28   any
            10    13    28   any
            19    22    28   any
```

Компилятор сгенерировал блок `finally` для успешного завершения блока `try`, для каждого блока `catch` и ещё один на тот случай, если исключение не было перехвачено. Причём последний начинается опкодом `astore_2`, а заканчивается опкодами - `aload_2` и `athrow`. Первый опкод сохраняет исключение из стека в переменную. Второй загружает его обратно после выполнения тела блока. А последний выбрасывает сохранённое исключение. То есть в норме, если исключение не было обработано, то должно быть выброшено повторно в конце блока `finally`. Но если добавить в блок `finally` инструкцию `return`, то все блоки становятся одинаковыми:

```
bipush        42
istore_0
ldc           #3  // String "finally"
areturn
```

Больше нет инструкции повторного выброса исключения. Получается, что исключение теряется из-за инструкции `return`.

Comment: Ничего себе. Спасибо за такое развернутое объяснение ^^

Answer (score 2):

> В блоке try происходит деление на 0, что должно породить:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Оно есть. Но на то и `try-catch-finally` блок, чтобы обрабатывать исключения. Т.к. блок `catch` отсутствует, то ничего и не делается (на самом деле делается, но остается внутри класса MyClass и наружу не отдается).

Если вынести функцию `getString` в `main()` класса `Test`, то увидите, что исключение есть и информация о нем выводится, а потом печатается "`finally`".

Answer (score 1):

У меня все работает:

> ```
> "finally"
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
>   at Main.main(Main.java:12)
> ```

Сначала происходит исключение, `try` его принимает, т.к. у вас нет блока `catch`, то оно не обрабатывается(а выходит в виде вывода выше). После этого программа переходит к выполнению блока `finally`. Блок `finally` выполняется всегда, независимо от того, было ли исключение, есть ли блок `catch`, и т.п.

Если бы у вас был такой код:

```
    try {
        i = i / 0;
        System.out.println("try");
    } catch(Exception ex)  {
        System.out.println("catch");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("finally);
    }
```

То был бы вывод:

> ```
> catch
> finally
> ```

[Хороший материал](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/exception.php) для новичков по исключениям.

Comment: Какая Java? У меня тоже исключение не выдаёт.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev 9. Но запускаю из IntelliJ

Comment: Вы этот код выполняете в `main`, а не отдельном методе?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в методе